# Regex not allow empty spaces at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

My target is to improve my regex. Regex need to everything except some special charaters, not to allow empty spaces at start, and not to allow empty spaces at the end.

```
^(?!\s*$)[^-\s][^`=~!@#$%^&*()[\]\/\\{}"|<>?]{3,100}$
```

Example:

`word` valid

`word [space]` invalid

`[space] word` invalid

`word w` valid

My regex did everything except empty space at the end. How to add this condition to forbit empty spaces at the end of regex?

Comment: `+` after `{3,100}` makes no sense.

Comment: @Barmar noted, I will remove it

Comment: out of curiosity, what is this for?  i note that it allows arbitrary unicode but not common punctuation, which seems unusual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add another negative lookahead to disallow space at the end:

```
^(?!\s*$)(?![^]*\s$)(?![-\s])[^`=~!@#$%^&*()[\]\/\\{}"|<>?]{3,100}$
```

`(?![^]*\s$)` is negative lookahead to assert that your regex won't allow a space at the end.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HqFhEj/1)

Comment: `(?!.*\s$)` is a wrong suggestion for a generic pattern that may match multiline text. It must be `(?![^]*\s$)` or `(?![\s\S]*\s$)`

Comment: Good point Wiktor, edited.